# Not getting value form getAll method in java Entity class

Tags: java, mysql, persistence

I have a pet entity class with some named queries, one of them like this:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Pet.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pet p")
```

I have a facade class, where I'm calling the method like such.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PetHospitaljpa");


public Collection<Pet> returnAllPets (){

    EntityManager  em = emf.createEntityManager();
    //vi laver en typed query for at specificere hvilken datatype, det er vi leder efter, i dette tilfælde er det en Pet
    TypedQuery<Pet> query = em.createNamedQuery("Pet.findAll", Pet.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Yet I get an empty collection in return whenever I call the method, I'm using the debugger and I can see that the query is empty, but why is this?

I have checked my MySQL database, and there is data inside.

Here is the data from my MySQL table:

[image: data from MySQL table]

Comment: Do the pets actually exist in the table "p" that you are selecting from?

Comment: Yes they do. I will edit, and post the MySQL query

Comment: Have you verified that you can connect to your SQL database in other ways?

Comment: I have tested the connection through my Persistence.xml file, but i have not made any other methods where i get data from the database no.

Comment: The reason was that I had my Persistence.xml, and drop and create so it deleted all the data from my database.

Comment: @javaprodigy The query you are referring to is not SQL, and **p** is not referring to a table or a column; it refers to an entity of type _Pet_. The code is using JPA and JPQL, not JDBC and SQL. See [Java Persistence/JPQL](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL) for an overview.

Comment: Your code looks OK. Could you post **persistence.xml**?